# Symbol for intervals

Tags: notation, terminology, interval-arithmetic

Set of integers is denoted by the symbol $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q[x]$ stands for univariate polynomials over rationals, etc.

Is there a symbol which indicates the set of all open (or closed) intervals over $\mathbb Z$? I know there is $[a,b]$ (which apparently means over $\mathbb R$) but does something like $\mathbb Z^2$ make sense (it doesn't say $a<b$)?

Comment: I would take $\mathbb Z^2$ to mean ordered pairs of integers (cf. $\mathbb R^2$).

Answer (score 0):

How about $$[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Z}$$ to emphasize integers as opposed to reals.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of interval analysis, the notation $\mathbb{I}\mathbb{R}$ is often used for the set of all closed intervals of the real line.

Comment: I don't really like it though, because $\mathbb I$ does not stand out clearly.

Comment: Is it also common to use it with other sets than reals, say rationals? I mean, for rationals, would it be also understandable?

Comment: Btw., $\mathbb{I}$ apparently also means [integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Doublestruck.html) or [imaginary numbers](https://oeis.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet).